# How many disk seeks does it take to write one row to a SQLite database?

Tags: csv, sqlite

I already asked this question [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3077/how-many-disk-seeks-does-it-take-to-write-one-row-on-sqlite) without getting any answers, so I allow myself to repost it here. I will provide references to where an answer was found.

As far as I understand, there can be one disk-seek per rotation of a harddisk, therefore I am interested to know how many disk seeks are needed for writing a row to an SQLite table, including locking etc. Assume that there are no indexes on the table (not even a primary key). I assume that there is one disk seek to write a line to a file? As you understand, I want to compare performance with writing the same data to a flat file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default its one transaction per disk rotation (roughly),

http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q19

The way to speedier writes is to wrap multiple ones inside a transaction.